# datatable stateSave multiple selection keep filter value selected

Tags: jquery, datatable, jquery-select2

How to Datatable keep value selected on header search, when do refresh page or back from browser. I am using select2.js for multiple selection and other are textbox field in header.

Input type="text" working good, but select option not working. #select_status is multi select field. below is the code i am using, any help would be appreciated.

```
function atol ( Date='',status='',invoice_due_date='', Nom_du_Client='',zip_code='', Reference_Client='',Reference_Document='', Montant_TTC='',amount_remaining='', centre_de_profit='' ,payment='', categorie='' ){
      var mytittle = 'hello';
        
        if($("#switch_on_off1").prop('checked') == true){
            var switch_on_off=1;
        }else{
            var switch_on_off=0;
        }
    
        var get_active_tab=$("#active_tabs").val();
        var select_status=$('#select_status').val();
        
        $("#atol").dataTable().fnDestroy();

        var rows_selected = [];
        var info = {};
        
        info["Date"] = Date;
        info["status"] = status;
        info["invoice_due_date"] = invoice_due_date;
        info["Nom_du_Client"] = Nom_du_Client;
        info["zip_code"] = zip_code;
        info["Reference_Client"] = Reference_Client;
        info["Reference_Document"] = Reference_Document;
        info["Montant_TTC"] = Montant_TTC;
        info["amount_remaining"] = amount_remaining;
        info["centre_de_profit"] = centre_de_profit;
        info["payment"] = payment;
        info["categorie"] = categorie;
          
        var atol=$("#atol").DataTable({
            "pagingType": 'first_last_numbers',
            orderCellsTop: true,
            stateSave: true,
            /* initComplete: function() {
                var api = this.api();
                var selected =  localStorage.getItem( 'atol' ).split(',');
                selected.forEach(function(s) {
                  api.row(s).select();
                });
            }, */
            'processing': true,
            "bAutoWidth": false, // Disable the auto width calculation 
            "serverSide": true,
            "responsive":false,
             dom: 'lBfrtip',
             "aoColumnDefs": [
                //{"width": 230, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]}
                {"width": 130, "aTargets": [ 0]},
                {"width": 150, "aTargets": [5,2]},
                {"width": 200, "aTargets": [3,6]},
                {"width": 160, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 10,11]},
                {"width": 150, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1]},
                {"width": 150, "aTargets": [4,7,8,9]},
                
        
            ],
            "drawCallback": function( settings ) 
            {
            //  $("#idtable thead").remove();
                $(".btn_amt").html(settings.json.total_late_payment);
                $(".btn_cust").html(settings.json.total_customer);
                $(".negative_payment").html(settings.json.negative_payment);
                $(".negative_amt").html(settings.json.negative_invoices_total);
                
                $(".total_invoices").html(settings.json.cust);
            },
            "searching" : true,
            'ajax': {
              'url':'./includes/facturer_invoice.php',
              'type':"GET",
              'data':  {info:info,datepicker_to:$("#datepicker_to").val(),datepicker_from:$("#datepicker_from").val(),datepicker_from_due:$("#datepicker_from_due").val(),datepicker_to_due:$("#datepicker_to_due").val(),switch_on_off:switch_on_off,get_active_tab:get_active_tab,select_status:select_status}
                /* 'success': function(result_data) {
                    $(".btn_amt").html(result.total_late_payment);
                    $(".btn_cust").html(result.cust);
                } */
            },
          
          'order': [0, 'desc'], 
         
          'rowCallback': function(row, data, dataIndex){
             // Get row ID
             var rowId = data[0];

             // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
             if($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1){
                $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                $(row).addClass('selected');
             }
          },
             "buttons": [
        /*  {
               "extend": 'copy',
               "text": '<i class="fa fa-files-o" style="color: green;"></i>',
               "titleAttr": 'Copy',                               
               "action": newexportaction            
            }, */
            {
               "extend": 'excel',
               "text": '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" style="color: green;"> </i>Export',
               "titleAttr": 'Excel',                               
               "action": newexportaction,
                "exportOptions": {
                    format: {
                        header: function ( data, columnIdx ) {
                            if(columnIdx==0 || columnIdx==1 || columnIdx==2 || columnIdx==3 || columnIdx==4|| columnIdx==5|| columnIdx==6|| columnIdx==7|| columnIdx==8|| columnIdx==9|| columnIdx==10|| columnIdx==11|| columnIdx==12){
                                return dataheader[columnIdx];
                            }
                            else{
                                return data;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
           /*,  {
               "extend": 'csv',
               "text": '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o" style="color: green;"></i>',
               "titleAttr": 'CSV',                               
               "action": newexportaction
            },
            {
               "extend": 'pdf',
               "text": '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style="color: green;"></i>',
               "titleAttr": 'PDF',                               
               "action": newexportaction
            },
            {
               "extend": 'print',
               "text": '<i class="fa fa-print" style="color: green;"></i>',
               "titleAttr": 'Print',                                
               "action": newexportaction
            } */
            ],
            /* buttons: ['csvHtml5',
              'copyHtml5',
              {
                  extend: 'excelHtml5',
                  title: mytittle,
                  customize: function ( xlsx ) {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                    
                    var count = 0;
                    var skippedHeader = false;
                    $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).each( function () {
                      if (skippedHeader) {
                        $('row c[r*="10"]', sheet).attr( 's', '25' );
                        count++;
                      }
                      else {
                        skippedHeader = true;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  
            }], */
          
        'columns': [
             { data: 'Date' },
             { data: 'status' },
             { data: 'invoice_due_date' },
             { data: 'Nom_du_Client' },
             { data: 'zip_code' },
             { data: 'Reference_Client' },
             { data: 'Reference_Document' },
             { data: 'Montant_TTC' },            
             { data: 'amount_remaining' },
             { data: 'centre_de_profit' },
             { data: 'payment' },
             { data: 'categorie' } 
          ] 
       });
       
    
       
       
       
          atol.columns().every(function () {
            var atol = this;  
             $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (atol.search() !== this.value) {
                       atol.search(this.value).draw();
                }
            }); 
            
             
            
            
            $('select#select_status', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                var arr = [];
                i = 0;
                $("#select_status  :selected").each(function() {
                    
                    arr[i++] = this.value;
                });
                
                atol.search(arr.toString()).draw();
            });
            
            $('select#cat_de_payment', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                var arr1 = [];
                i = 0;
                $("#cat_de_payment  :selected").each(function() {
                    
                    arr1[i++] = this.value;
                });
                
                atol.search(arr1.toString()).draw();
            });
            
             
            /* var select=  $("select#select_status");
            
            var input = $('<input type="text" />')
            var state = this.state.loaded();
            if (state) {
                
                console.log(this.index());
                    
                if(this.index()==1){
                    var val = state.columns[this.index()];
                    //console.log(val);
                    select.val(val.search.search);
                }else{
                    var val = state.columns[this.index()];
                //  console.log(val);
                    input.val(val.search.search);   
                }
                
            }
             displaySearch();  */
          }); 
        
        /* atol.on('search.dt', function() {
             displaySearch();
        }); */
        
         
        
}

       $("#atol").on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
            var data = $("#atol").DataTable().row(this).data();
            $("#fac_id").html(data.Reference_Document);
            window.location.href="invoice_detail.php?ref_doc="+data.Reference_Document+"&client="+data.Reference_Client;
            $("#ref_doc_in").val(data.Reference_Document);
            fac_id_comments(data.Reference_Document);
            other_invoices(data.Reference_Client);
            
            
            $("#ref_docmt").val(data.Reference_Document);
            $("#ref_id").val(data.Reference_Client);
            $("#Montant_TTC").val(data.Montant_TTC);
            
            
            //$('#clickModal').modal('show');
        });


        $('#atol thead th').each(function(i) {
            var title1 = $('#atol thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
            
            if(i==1){
                /* $(this).html("<select id='select_status' class='form-select' style='width:100%;'>"+
                "<option>Select Status</option>"+
                "<option value='1st Call'>1st call</option>"+
                "<option value='1st Mail'>1st Mail</option>"+
                "<option value='2nd call'>2nd call</option>"+
                "<option value='2nd Mail'>2nd Mail</option>"+
                "</select>"); */
                
                
                $(this).html("<select id='select_status' class='form-select select2 select2-hidden-accessible' multiple='' style='width:100%;' tabindex='-1' aria-hidden='true'><option>Select Status</option></select>");
                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: './includes/ajax_request.php',
                    dataType:'html',
                    data: {status_invoice:1},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#select_status').append(data);
                    }
                });
                
                 
            }else if(i==10){
                $(this).html("<select id='cat_de_payment' class='form-select select2 select2-hidden-accessible' multiple='' style='width:100%;' tabindex='-1' aria-hidden='true'><option>Search payment</option></select>");
                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: './includes/ajax_request.php',
                    dataType:'html',
                    data: {payment:1},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#cat_de_payment').append(data);
                    }
                });
                
                 
            }else if(i==11){
                $(this).html("<select id='cat_de_client' class='form-select select2 select2-hidden-accessible' multiple='' style='width:100%;' tabindex='-1' aria-hidden='true'><option>Search Catégorie de client</option></select>");
                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: './includes/ajax_request.php',
                    dataType:'html',
                    data: {lmb_category:1},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#cat_de_client').append(data);
                    }
                });
                
                 
            }else{
                $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ' + title1 + '" style="width:100%;"/>');
            }
        });
```